# Rails Microposts Show all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so, following M. Hartl's Tutorial, I have this static_pages controller that displays this

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
def home
if signed_in?
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
  @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
end

def help
end

def about
end

def contact
end
end
```

And this makes it show on the home page, all of the current users' microposts, but only the current users

how do i make it show ALL Users micropost, every single one created?

Answer (score 2):

You are scoping the query to fetch only the `current_user` microposts. `Micropost.all` should get you all microposts. Also ensure that you havent already set some default scopes in your model, in which case you will have to use `Micropost.unscoped`.

Comment: so           
@feed_items = Micropost.all.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
??

Comment: In your question i see feed is related to User, but the above comment indicates a relation between Micropost and Feed. Can you post the relations between User, microposts and feed ? Micropost.all.feed will work if you have proper methods defined which will return all feeds for an array of Microposts.

Comment: I dont follow 
What exactly do you need me to upload

Comment: How are Micropost, User and Feed related to each other ? the has_many, has_one etc between them are called their relations btw.